# Read bytes from file, save it to struct and modify values

Tags: go

I am a completely newbie to Go. I watched the [Coursera Introduction to Go Language](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/google-golang), but some topics are not covered in depth.

To practice Go I'm solving as many exercises as I can from [CS50](https://cs50.harvard.edu/) . I'm now working on an [example](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/4/bottomup/) in which I need to read a bmp file, copy the headers content to the correspondent data structure, change some parameters in this structure, and then copy the result to a new file.

The first thing I noticed is that I cannot read as binary the number of bytes correspondent to the size of the struct I created. This is due to padding that may happen when building a struct. I was able to read field by field and filled up the struct.

In order to improve this, I tried to iterate through the structure, get the size of each field, read from the file the correspondent number of bytes and then write to the file, again, after iterating through the structure.

I'm stuck in the last step (if the previous steps were done correctly): How can I correctly set the values depending on the type of field?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

type DWORD uint32
type WORD uint16
type BITMAPFILEHEADER struct {
    BfType      WORD
    BfSize      DWORD
    BfReserved1 WORD
    BfReserved2 WORD
    BfOffBits   DWORD
}

func main() {
    input_file, err := os.Open("harvard_bottomup.bmp")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not open the origin file.")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var bf BITMAPFILEHEADER
    reader := bufio.NewReader(input_file)

    value := reflect.ValueOf(&bf).Elem()
    n := value.NumField()
    structType := value.Type()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {

        b := make([]byte, structType.Field(i).Type.Size())
        err = binary.Read(reader, binary.BigEndian, b)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Field Name: %-15s %-15s  %02x\n", structType.Field(i).Name, structType.Field(i).Type, b)
        // I should now set the value, but I don't know how to switch between types
        // value.Field(i).Set...
    }

    input_file.Close()
}
```

PS: Before that I tried to read directly to the fields within the struct, but I could not do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are duplicating functionality in the [binary.Read](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#Read) function. The function decodes data in the specified byte order to successive fields in a struct.  You can view struct decoding code [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/ee788dbae0fc8e074fc66fc76f0597200b443950/src/encoding/binary/binary.go#L626-L640).

Here's how to use Read to decode the file header:

```
input_file, err := os.Open("harvard_bottomup.bmp")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Could not open the origin file.")
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer input_file.Close()
reader := bufio.NewReader(input_file)

var bf BITMAPFILEHEADER
err = binary.Read(reader, binary.BigEndian, &bf)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
```

Comment: Hi @Brother Constant, thank you very much for your answer. This indeed worked, thanks for the help, I will take a look at the references you provided so I can have a better understanding of how Go works!